# ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) in httpclient using json webservice and multipartentity

Tags: android, json, sockets

How to resolve this ........

I/System.out(11369): [CDS]write is:1557/4096
I/SurfaceTextureClient(11369): [0x5269b9c0] frames:10, duration:1.018000, fps:9.820543
I/System.out(11369): [CDS]close[40261]
I/System.out(11369): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:40261]
I/System.out(11369): ex:java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
I/System.out(11369): retry1
I/System.out(11369): [socket][4] connection /172.17.83.69:8080;LocalPort=47979(120000)
I/System.out(11369): [CDS]connect[/172.17.83.69:8080] tm:120

code is------ It is in AsyncTask doInBackground method

```
      HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
      HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 2*60*1000);
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient( httpParameters);

      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
      MultipartEntity se = new MultipartEntity();
```

//adding string fields

```
            se.addPart("name_of_ol1", newStringBody(ol_name_mand.getText().toString()));
            se.addPart("name_of_ol2", new StringBody(olname2.getText().toString()));
```

// adding image file with file name

```
            se.addPart("file", new FileBody(imageFilename));
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
```

//executing

```
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity e = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

Comment: A little bit code would be helpful, also some information on what You try to achieve. I tried to contact to http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Cayce but his line was occupied.

Comment: I am uploading some string data with an image file via HttpPost.Multipartentity is used for adding data then httpclient execute is performed. In some cases data is uploaded else this exception occured.  ex:java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Comment: Is multipartentity really necessary?